# Java OOP concept

Tags: java, oop, object-oriented-analysis

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

From the above, if we say that `MyClass` is the class and `public static void main(String[] args)`  is the method, then I would like to know what part of the code would be considered as the Object.

If we say that classes have objects and objects have methods, then in the code above, which part is the object? Is there any object created here?

Comment: Short answer; an object is an instance of a class

Comment: @RaduMurzea actually it's harder to explain for a starter...so less answers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`static` methods don't belong to object references but to classes instead. You can execute a `static` method without creating an instance of the class. Knowing this, the only object references that would be created here would be:

- `String[] args` object
- Every `String` inside `args` array
- `"Hello world"` `String`.

Note that `args` and its contents aren't created by you, the JVM will do it (thanks to Thilo's comment).

Comment: And those Strings are not created by your code, either (the JVM launcher does that automatically).

Comment: There are only two objects definitely created here - `"Hello World!"` and the array `args`.

Comment: Actually, the String literal "Hello World" can be said to be created by the main method (even though that is not strictly true with the ways strings work either)

Comment: +1 and.. Dont know if this will help of confuse more, but `out` is a `PrintStream` object :P

Comment: Also arg contents will be created only if arguments are sent to main mehod while executing the program. Else only 1 and 3 are applicable as per OP.

Comment: @HarishKumar that will depend if OP doesn't send any argument when executing the application.

Comment: @pinkpanther AFAIK that happens on C/C++. In Java, the program/application name is not sent as parameter. See [ideone example](http://ideone.com/DZIRTP).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Yes that is correct. I will correct the language of my comment. Thanks for highlighting.

Comment: wow! thank you all for your help, I didnt expect this a lot of comments and answers, I just had a simple question. last thing, so if by doing `MyClass mc = new MyClass()` would it create an `Object` of `MyClass` by the name of `mc` ?

Comment: Sir @LuiggiMendoza thank you very much. I just wanted this to be cleared out before I would teach it to my students :) thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In above case no object of your class is created. To do that you need to write:

```
MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
```

Answer (score 0):

No object created there.Because that is a main method where the program starts.
If it is not a `static`,otherwise, it would need an `instance` of the object to be executed.

Comment: What about `"Hello world"` `String`?

Answer (score 0):

Static Method no need to create object for execution. When you load the class the static members on the class are loaded automatically by JVM.

Specially for execution in Java the JVM find the `main` method and execute it from the beginning of execution.

Then, each statement from the `main` method is executed until the termination point.

In the main method what is `String args[]` it is an array of objects, which is useful when you need to pass the parameters via command line.

So, finally `static` method execute on **when the class is loaded** on **JVM**. So we don't need instance/object for the `main` method execution

So when is the main method is loaded on JVM? It's loaded when you initialize to create any objects like this

```
MyClass myobj = new MyClass();
```

It calls the default constructor `MyClass()` and load the class

Answer (score 0):

In the code you provided, there isn't any object created explicitly. The 'MyClass' is just a class definition, and the 'main' method is the one that gets executed when you run the program.

In object-oriented programming, objects are instances of classes. They have variables (attributes) and methods (behaviors). However, in this code snippet, there's no object created or used inside the 'main' method.

If you want to create an object of the 'MyClass' class, you can do that by using the 'new' keyword like this:

```
MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
```

This line of code creates a new object of the 'MyClass' type and stores it in the 'myObject' variable. After creating the object, you can access its methods and variables using the dot notation, like 'myObject.someMethod()'.

enter code here